# Escaping & for display in mail client (mailto link)

Tags: javascript, urlencode, encode

I have a JavaScript function like so:

```
var strBody = encodeURI(window.location.href);
var strSubject = encodeURI(document.title);
var mailto_link = "mailto:?subject=" + encodeURI(strSubject) + "&body=" + strBody;
```

This code is executed on a hyperlink's onclick event, and opens the mail client (mailto://). However, the title of the page has several & symbols, but the title is only picked up until the first &. The url is always picked up.

What is the correct JavasSript to escape the & and display it in the mail client's subject line?

Answer (score 20):

```
var encoded_body = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
var encoded_subject = encodeURIComponent(document.title);
var mailto_link = "mailto:?subject=" + encoded_subject + "&body=" + encoded_body;
```

should do it (`encodeURIComponent` instead of `encodeURI`).

In your original code you were also incorrectly double encoding the *subject* (once on line 2, and then again on line 3).

I took the liberty of renaming your variables to make it clearer that they contain the encoded *subject* and *body*, as opposed to the original text.

Comment: Don't use `escape`, it is deprecated because it doesn't work properly.

Comment: @Quentin Well spotted. I’ve kind of nicked your answer now, sorry :).

Comment: That didn't work either? For a title like a & b & c, I can only get "a".

Comment: @gss5: It works for me, I tested in Chrome and IE in conjunction with Outlook. Perhaps you are running into an incompatibility with a specific mail client?

Comment: @gss5: It sounds like your mail client is behaving oddly. Which mail client(s) have you tested?

Answer (score 2):

You want [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) not encodeURI.