# URL deformed when inserted in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Correct URL printed in console:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.387138,-122.083237&zoom=15&size=200x200&key=API_KEY
```

I get the following when I insert it into html

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.386337,-122.085823%E2%80%A65&size=200x200&maptype=roadmap&key=API_KEY
```

What could be causing this problem? I do encode the URL so I'm not sure what's the issue here.

JavaScript function:

```
function genStaticMap(mapObj, elemID, width, height, mapType){
var center = mapObj.lat + "," + mapObj.lng;     // define map center
var zoom = mapObj.radius;                       // get radius (zoom) of map
var altTag = mapObj.title;  // get alt tag for map
var mapURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" 
              + center + "&zoom=" + zoom + "&maptype=" + mapType 
              + "&size=" + width + "x" + height 
              +  "&key=" + API_KEY;
console.log(mapURL);
var mapURL = encodeURI(mapURL);
var staticMap = "<img src=\"" + mapURL + "\" alt=\"" + altTag + "\" />";
    $(staticMap).appendTo(elemID);                  // append map to element
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`var mapURL = encodeURI(mapURL);` is the likely culprit. Can you either remove that line, or move `console.log()` immediately following, to check?

Comment: Removed and I get the following: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.386337,-122.085823%E2%80%A65&size=200x200&maptype=roadmap&key=API_KEY

Comment: Can you try replacing all `&` instances on lines 5,6,7 with `&amp;` ?

Comment: Did it, now the zoom appears but the "&" have been replaced with "&amp;" which form an invalid request url

Comment: Wonder why it doesn't like &zoom keyword... also strangely looks like number `7` before zoom is being eaten, too?!

Comment: Oh the 7 is just different coordinates

Comment: Gotcha. Not as strange then ;) What happens if you move zoom to the end of the query? i.e. eliminate it between center &maptype, and adjust: `+ "&key=" + API_KEY + "&zoom=" + zoom;`

Comment: Or add it after you encode: `var mapURL = encodeURI(mapURL) + "&zoom=" + zoom;`

Comment: Could also see example here, where the individual parts are encoded rather than the complete URI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545709/escaping-for-display-in-mail-client-mailto-link

Comment: Found it! There was a problem with another function generating the second map I was seeing the url of. Flipping bugs. Thanks for your help mate :) Now I only have the bug of .appendTo() not actually appending anything *cries in corner*

Comment: Glad you're getting there! What are you passing in as elemID ?

Comment: You're right about that too haha, I was passing it the wrong way! Fixed. Man do I love coding when it works